# "Convergence" of bordered Riemann surfaces to a congruence surface

Tags: riemann-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

Let $\Gamma(N)$ be the principal congruence subgroup of level $N\geq 3$, $H$ the upper half-plane and $C(N)=H/\Gamma(N)$ be the corresponding Riemann surface. In his paper " Congruence Subgroups of Maximal Riemann Surfaces", Schmutz takes the pants-decomposition of $C(N)$ and replaces any cusp by a boundary geodesic of length $\delta>0$. The resulting surface will be denoted $C_\delta(N)$. Now, he writes $$C(N)=\lim\limits_{\delta\to 0} C_\delta(N)$$
While the intuition is clear, I am not so sure about the precise meaning. The surfaces $C(N)$ and $C_\delta(N)$ possess different signatures and hence (from what I understand) should not live in the same Teichmüller space. Is there some kind of Teichmüller space, which encapsulates both $C_\delta(N)$ and $C(N)$? Furthermore, do the lengths of closed geodesics on $C_\delta(N)$ approach for $\delta\to 0$ the lengths of closed geodesics on $C(N)$? I am grateful for any references and ideas.